# How to connect Ms SQL server with R on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: r, sql-server, rodbc, rjdbc

I am unable to connect R with MS sql using RODBC as well as RJDBC

**With RODBC**

```
library(RODBC)
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect(paste("driver={SQL Server};server=", sname, ";database=", 
                                      dbname, ";uid=", user,";pwd=",password, sep = ""))

res <- sqlFetch(dbhandle, client.table_name)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(paste("driver=SQL Server;server=", sname, ";database=",  :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found
2: In odbcDriverConnect(paste("driver=SQL Server;server=", sname, ";database=",  :
  ODBC connection failed
```

Also I have tried with **RJDBC**

```
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)

drv <- JDBC(driverClass="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
                  classPath="/home/****/sqljdbc_4.2/enu/jre8/sqljdbc42.jar")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, paste0("jdbc:sqlserver://",client.hostname),
                        user=client.username , password=client.password, dbname = client.dbName)
```

The error is

```
Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:253fd8d2-8e60-40fb-96b0-220745818166".
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error  when i put below code for connection to MSSQLSERVER

```
library(RODBC)
dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=SQL Server;Server=192.168.76.60; Database=kaggle;Uid=sa; Pwd=1234")
```

It throws to me

```
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found
```

**why this Error thrown?**
Answer: when we fail to put proper ODBC version name on Driver value.

**From where we can get Driver ODBC version name**

inside  "/etc" folder you will find "odbcinst.ini" file open it and check the version name

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.1.so.0.1
UsageCount=1
```

so i got ODBC Driver name from here , it will be "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
Then i modify my connection string

```
library(RODBC)
dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;Server=192.168.76.60; Database=kaggle;Uid=sa; Pwd=1234")
```

And it works fine

Comment: In odbcDriverConnect(paste("driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;server=",  :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 87, message [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: @Shubh have you followed each steps

Comment: yes , i have this in my odbc.inst.ini    [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]

Comment: @Shubh your erroe is different it says network related problem so i think either you puted wron server name or server is  unreachable